# Query on Simple_form Associations in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, simple-form

I have this below code in my simple_form, As it gives me the drop down,I want to modify it as a search box, where i can search for it instead of a drop dow. How to modify it ?

Does simple_form has any feature like this or we need to use any jquery plugin for this ? If YES please tell me how modfiy it accordingly.

`<%= f.association :receiver, :label => "Member's Name" %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `chosen-rails` gem. Just follow the [README](https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails).

Comment: THanks dude..right on target :) ...is there anyway we can remove the dropdown for association and just show "search" field ?

Comment: Sincerely, I don't know how to use a text field instead of dropdown with Chosen, but I think you can use it with **jQuery-TokenInput** plugin, as Ryan Bates shows in [railscast #258](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised). Check it out the [`jquery-tokeninput-rails`](https://github.com/foohey/jquery-tokeninput-rails) gem.